# Ignite Java .NET interoperability java.sql.Timestamp to System.DateTime

Tags: ignite

I have a topology like this.
1 server node running on java
1 client node running on .net

I have a simple type defined on both platforms which has a field

```
java.sql.Timestamp lastUpdated
```

on the java side, and

```
DateTime? LastUpdated { get; set; }
```

on the .net side

I can load the objects onto the java node and .net client node without any problems. I can also create new instances and put them to the cache from the java node. However, when I try to put a new object to the cache from the .net node, I get the below exception (from the java side log). Note that if I remove this date field or set it to null, then I can put objects from the .net side without problems.

Any ideas?
Thanks.

```
[ERROR] 2016-12-09 14:21:48.121 [sys-#24%null%] GridDhtAtomicCache - <D9Cache> Unexpected exception during cache update
org.apache.ignite.binary.BinaryObjectException: Unexpected flag value [pos=33, expected=33, actual=103]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.checkFlagNoHandles(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1423) ~[ignite-core-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.readTimestamp(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1075) ~[ignite-core-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.readTimestamp(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1070) ~[ignite-core-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryFieldAccessor$DefaultFinalClassAccessor.readFixedType(BinaryFieldAccessor.java:722) ~[ignite-core-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryFieldAccessor$DefaultFinalClassAccessor.read(BinaryFieldAccessor.java:639) ~[ignite-core-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryClassDescriptor.read(BinaryClassDescriptor.java:776) ~[ignite-core-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.deserialize(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1481) ~[ignite-core-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryObjectImpl.deserializeValue(BinaryObjectImpl.java:585) ~[ignite-core-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryObjectImpl.value(BinaryObjectImpl.java:142) ~[ignite-core-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.CacheObjectContext.unwrapBinary(CacheObjectContext.java:272) ~[ignite-core-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.CacheObjectContext.unwrapBinaryIfNeeded(CacheObjectContext.java:160) ~[ignite-core-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.CacheObjectContext.unwrapBinaryIfNeeded(CacheObjectContext.java:147) ~[ignite-core-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheContext.unwrapBinaryIfNeeded(GridCacheContext.java:1752) ~[ignite-core-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.store.GridCacheStoreManagerAdapter.put(GridCacheStoreManagerAdapter.java:565) ~[ignite-core-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheMapEntry.innerUpdate(GridCacheMapEntry.java:2425) ~[ignite-core-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache.updateSingle(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:2252) ~[ignite-core-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache.updateAllAsyncInternal0(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:1652) [ignite-core-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache.updateAllAsyncInternal(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:1490) [ignite-core-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache.processNearAtomicUpdateRequest(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:2950) [ignite-core-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache.access$600(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:130) [ignite-core-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache$5.apply(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:268) [ignite-core-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache$5.apply(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:266) [ignite-core-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.processMessage(GridCacheIoManager.java:748) [ignite-core-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.onMessage0(GridCacheIoManager.java:353) [ignite-core-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.handleMessage(GridCacheIoManager.java:277) [ignite-core-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.access$000(GridCacheIoManager.java:88) [ignite-core-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager$1.onMessage(GridCacheIoManager.java:231) [ignite-core-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.invokeListener(GridIoManager.java:1238) [ignite-core-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.processRegularMessage0(GridIoManager.java:866) [ignite-core-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.access$1700(GridIoManager.java:106) [ignite-core-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager$5.run(GridIoManager.java:829) [ignite-core-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_102]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_102]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_102]
```

Answer (score 2):

.NET `DateTime` can be Local and UTC; Java `Timestamp` can only be UTC. Because of that, Ignite.NET can serialize `DateTime` in two ways: .NET style (can work with non-UTC values, does not work in Java and SQL) and as `Timestamp` (throws exception on non-UTC values, works properly in Java and SQL).

Simple workaround is to mark field with `[QuerySqlField]` to enforce `Timestamp` serialization.

You can also use implement `IBinarizable` and use `IBinaryWriter.WriteTimestamp` method.

When it is not possible to modify class to mark fields with `[QuerySqlField]` or implement `IBinarizable`, use `IBinarySerializer` approach.

See https://apacheignite-net.readme.io/docs/platform-interoperability#type-compatibility for more details.